# If someone says "They insisted that he left", is there any ambiguity in BrE or in AmE?

Tags: meaning, british-english, subjunctive-mood, transatlantic-differences

Do they mean something like "please go!  You must leave!" or could it be "We assure you that he left"?

Comment: That person would say "They insisted that he **leave**" (not "left"). It means they threw him out.

Comment: @Robusto  In BrE too?

Comment: _We assure you that he left; we insist on going on record._ Only. It's not subjunctive, because _left_ is past tense, and _insist_ takes a tenseless infinitive to mark the subjunctive, like _They insisted that he leave_.

Comment: It's ambiguous and non-idiomatic.  If they were insisting that this persona non grata had already vacated the premises it would be "The insisted that he *had* left."  While that's what the original statement appears to mean, it's non-idomatic nature leaves one wondering if the other meaning were intended (especially when coming from someone who apparently does not speak English well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that @tchrist assures us there can be no ambiguity in AmE, I feel I should post the contrary position. Which I can't substantiate as representing BrE in general, but it's certainly how ***I*** see it.

There's no doubt the untensed "infinitive/subjunctive" *They insisted [that] he leave* only ever means that what they demanded (of *him*, or whoever controlled his actions) was that he ***should*** leave.

But to me at least,...

> [*She insisted that we **went** into the house and **shared** the meal they were just about to have.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22She%20insisted%20that%20we%20went%20into%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

...is perfectly acceptable. But if it weren't for this question reminding me of a possible (perverse) interpretation, it would never occur to me to think it might mean she insistently claimed later that this is what happened.

In short, I don't think it's particularly uncommon (or generally perceived to be a significant error) to use *X insisted that Y **Z'ed*** to mean they were adamant that *Y **should** do Z* (was required to, at the time). The alternative interpretation - insistence that *Y **did in fact** do Z* - may be equally credible in some contexts, so I would simply say the construction itself is inherently ambiguous.

Comment: Dissenting opinion here about Am English -- I've *never* heard anyone do this with the meaning Fumble gave.

Comment: @aparente001: I must admit I'm rather surprised by the reaction here (two *downvotes*, as of now). Obviously I'm aware of the strict grammatical position, and I assume OP is too. But I got my cited example by searching Google Books for [insisted that we went](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22She+insisted+that+we+went+into%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=cr&ei=S17YVfufLuSu7AbHvK3oAw#tbm=bks&q=%22insisted+that+we+went%22). ***Three of the four results*** where the full context is accessible are for the supposedly "incorrect" sense - in my book it's unquestionably "ambiguous".

Answer (score 6):

In American English, there is no ambiguity. There is no issue with it being idiomatic; it is. Your sentence is in the indicative for us:

> They insisted that he left.

That version *always* means that they are assuring you that he has indeed departed. It is a done deal.

Had we meant the other thing, we would have said this, using an untensed verb in the subordinate clause to indicate subjunctive effect:

> They insisted that he leave.

Which means that they had demanded his departure. Whether he actually left or not is unstated.

Comment: I do not think this is uniquely American. I see no difference here, in the way the two separate ideas would be expressed in Britain.

Comment: @WS2  Here is what I read about it:  "Paralleling the American retention of the mandative subjunctive ("They insisted that he leave") is a British innovative use of the indicative in such expressions: "They insisted that he left.""    From the answers and comments I've read so far, it seems ths innovative use does not exist.  (?)

Comment: [source](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=-3YokgYKoJMC&pg=PT224&lpg=PT224&dq=Paralleling+the+American+retention+of+the+mandative+subjunctive&source=bl&ots=2gHHm7CDT-&sig=DORobyxYpXCZto7xDbcD1297qCw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI8taEkoe4xwIVBh2QCh2_ZQ8v#v=onepage&q=Paralleling%20the%20American%20retention%20of%20the%20mandative%20subjunctive&f=false) page 180.

Comment: @Centaurus Well I'm no linguistics scholar, but to my way of thinking it would mean that they were insisting to others that 'he' had left. e.g. *they insisted, to the policeman's enquiries, that the suspect left at 10.30pm'

Comment: I now realize that I've so phrased my question that it allows for two correct answers, one AmE and the other BrE.  I'm sorry that I can accept only one.  Thank you for your answer @tchrist.